# Accurev - Environment Ignore Rules not applied in 64-bit machine

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit, accurev

I recently installed the 64 bit version of XP on my new development machine, and subsequently installed AccuRev. One thing I noted was that the ignore rules I previously used on my 32 bit machine in the ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS environment variable are not being applied.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: I'm running AccuRev on an XP x64 machine at work. Using ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS and it works fine. What version of AccuRev and what's the install path? Can you share the exact ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS value?

Comment: My ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS is the following:

*.suo */Thumbs.db */bin */obj */bin/* */obj/* */TestResults/* */Bin/* */*.pdb */*.vsmdi */*.testrunconfig RECYCLER

The install path for AccuRev is C:\Program Files (x86)\AccuRev, and it is version 4.7.0.

As mentioned the above ACCUREV_IGNORE_ELEMS works on the 32 bit machine I had previously, however on the 64 bit machine it will list files that should be ignored. For example all the files in the TestResults directory will be listed under external items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a file placed in the root directory of the project, that included the files to be ignored. Then had accurev make use of that instead, still not sure why I had to take this route but it worked.